# how to set parameter for date plus days in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have problem to add set parameter for date plus days in oracle. i have two parameter. that is one for **date** and one for **day**. I have tried that way but not successful.

This my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  mhn.id_mohon,
  mhn.kod_urusan,
  mhn.kod_caw,
  nvl(to_char(mhn.trh_masuk, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '-') trh_mohon,
  nvl(to_char(mhn.trh_masuk, 'MM'), '-')         bln
 FROM mohon mhn
WHERE mhn.trh_masuk = to_date(:p_date1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + INTERVAL :days DAY;
```

Can you check what the problem is my parameter?

Comment: 'Not successful' is not a recognised error message. Please add what you actually see - I'd guess an OA-00923 maybe?

Comment: but my result is not appear. i don't know what problem is my parameter.can you check where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect that you need:

```
to_date(:p_date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + :days
```

or:

```
to_date(:p_date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + :days * INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 3):

An [interval literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221) shows that the interval length has to be a quoted fixed value; it cannot be a variable.

You can use the [`numtodsinterval()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions117.htm) instead:

```
mhn.trh_masuk = to_date(:p_date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + numtodsinterval(:days, 'DAY')
```

Or you could just [add the number of days to the date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208):

```
mhn.trh_masuk = to_date(:p_date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + :days
```

Comment: but what datatype should i use? varchar,number,nvarchar or date

Comment: @AminSCO - data type for what? 'p_date1` is a `varchar2`, and `:days` is a `number`.

Comment: ok2.i got it.to_date(mhn.trh_masuk,'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_date(:p_date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + :days * INTERVAL '1' DAY. i use  'p_date1` is a date, and :days is a varchar.Thank you :)

Comment: Isn't `trh_masuk` already a `DATE` field? Using `to_char()` in the `select` suggests it is. Seems like you will end up doing an implicit conversion like this, one way or the other, which is always a bad idea. (Not sure why you'd have `:days` as a `varchar2` instead of a number, and I prefer `numtodsinterval()` over the multiplication, but whatever works for you I suppose... *8-)

Comment: yes,thh_masuk is date but when i not put the to_date, the result is not appear. i also has change :days to number.then the result is appear.i don't know what the problem with my oracle.and my answer more to "to_date(:p_date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + :days"